# How to stop the variable from resetting after switching case?

Tags: c++, class, variables, initialization, switch-statement

I'm new to C++. I am trying to write a program that will ask the user to choose:

[a] input the number [b] read the number [q] quit the program

If the user chooses a, then he will be asked to input a number and the program will save it.
If the user chooses b, the program will display the inputted number.
It the user chooses q, the program will quit.

However, in my program, I cannot figure out after the user entered the number and choose to read it, the variable 'storage' will be reset and cannot show the inputted number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class cNumber       //declare the class
{
public:     void WriteRead(char cmd);       //a for write; b for read
            bool Quit();

private:    int storage;
            int input;

};

void cNumber::WriteRead(char cmd) {
    if (cmd == 'a') {
        cout << "input:\n";
        cin >> input;
        storage = input;
    }

    if (cmd == 'b') {
        cout << "Here is your number:\n" << storage << endl;
    }
}

bool cNumber::Quit() {
    return true;
}

bool menu();
int main() {
    bool exitflag = false;
    while (exitflag == false) {
        exitflag = menu();
    }

    return 0;
}

bool menu() {
    cNumber Test;
    char choice;  // To store the command of user
    cout << "[a] Write number\n" << "[b] Read number\n" << "[q] Quit\n";
    cout << "Please enter your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch (choice) {
    case'a':
        Test.WriteRead('a');
        cout << "Write thx\n"; break;
    case 'b':
        cout << "Test Read\n";
        Test.WriteRead('b');
        cout << "\nRead thx\n"; break;
    case 'q':
        cout << "\nCloseeeee";
        return Test.Quit();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: int storage is the global variable that I have trouble with.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2017. And the user will see -858993460 if they read the number after inputting.

Comment: _@AustinL_ Sorry, I just didn't spot the `break;` when I've edited your code, because I expected them at a separate line. Your code formatting is very unusual.

Comment: Oh, really sorry about my poor formatting style as I am very new to C++. I will try to make it look better next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `bool menu()` function, this

```
cNumber Test;
```

is a **local `cNumber` object** which will be destroyed from the stack at the **end of function scope**. That means what you storing to private `storage` variable will be also be gone with that.

Next time when you call `bool menu()` function again, you are **creating another object** of `cNumber`, which has nothing to do with what you have done before. Therefore, the `storage` contains nothing but some garbage value, since it has not been inilitied in this function scope. Trying to access uninitialized variable will be *[undefined behavior.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)*

The solution is to have a single `cNumber` instance in the `main()` program and pass it to the function each time by reference.

That means, change the code to:

```
/* other code */
bool menu(cNumber& Test);
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^
int main() {

    bool exitflag = false;
    cNumber Test;              // create a single instance for entire program
    while (exitflag == false)
    {
        exitflag = menu(Test); // and pass to the function by ref
    }

    return 0;
}

bool menu(cNumber& Test) // and pass to the function by ref
{ 
  char choice;
  // remaing code
}
```

---

**Edit**: As OP requested to see a solution without having constructors, alternatively, the member variables can be initialized inside the class, provided that C++11 or later versions should be used.

Here is a example code which compiles in both **[MSVS2017 and GCC8.2](https://godbolt.org/z/T903yr)**

Comment: However, there is a error show regarding

Comment: Sorry, I edited the previous comment wrongly. I tried but there is an error regarding this line of code: exitflag = menu(Test);

Comment: It said Code C4700 uninitialized local variable 'Test' used.

Comment: C4700 uninitialized local variable 'Test' used

Comment: @AustinL Then I suggest providing a **explicit**  constructor like this: `explicit cNumber(int s, int i): storage(s), input(i) {}` and initialize the object at creation  with some initial values for `storage` and `input` like `cNumber Test(1,2);`

Comment: Since I haven't learnt explicit yet, I cannot use it in this program. Is that any other ways to do it instead of using explicit?

Comment: Sorry, no... I hope I have learnt it.

Comment: Are there any other ways that I can use to achieve the same goal?

Comment: @AustinL You will definitely learn about constructors as you jumped in OOPs world. However, for now, you actually do not need to specify any of them as the [C++ compiler will take care of it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor).(compiler wil generate for you if you did not mentioned any of it: That means **problem solved for now** :) ). On the other hand, you can provide **default values to the member variables** inside the class itself. See [this code which compiles in both MSVS2017 and GCC8.2](https://godbolt.org/z/T903yr)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I will try it later :)